# How to call function in macro in a DBT model?

Tags: dbt

I wrote the following macro:

```
{% macro calculate_func(given_price,
                        amount,
                        new_tariff_ec_h,
                        deposit_gross,
                        tariff_bp_gross,
                        new_tariff_bp_gross,
                        product_lt_percentage,
                        tariff_ec_ht,
                        new_tariff_ec_lt) %}
  {% if given_price > 0.10 %}

    round(((0.9 * {{amount}} * 0.10) + (0.1 * {{amount}} * {{new_tariff_ec_h}}))  , 2)

  {% elif amount> 30000 %}

    round(((0.8 * {{amount}} * 0.10) + (0.2 * {{amount}} * {{new_tariff_ec_h}})), 2)

  {% else %}

    round(
        {{deposit_gross}} -
        ( {{tariff_bp_gross}} - {{new_tariff_bp_gross}}
            + {{amount}} * (100-{{product_lt_percentage}}) * ({{tariff_ec_ht}} - {{new_tariff_ec_h}})
            + {{amount}} * {{product_lt_percentage}} * ({{tariff_ec_lt}} - {{new_tariff_ec_lt}})
        ) 
    ,0)
  {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

I called it from the DBT model in this way :

```
select
{{
    calculate_func(given_price,
        amount,
        new_tariff_ec_h,
        deposit_gross,
        tariff_bp_gross,
        new_tariff_bp_gross,
        product_lt_percentage,
        tariff_ec_ht,
        new_tariff_ec_lt,
    )
}} as amount_glb
from {{ ref("my_table") }}
```

i tried to call it this way also but same result:

```
select
{{
    calculate_func('given_price',
        'amount',
        'new_tariff_ec_h',
        'deposit_gross',
        'tariff_bp_gross',
        'new_tariff_bp_gross',
        'product_lt_percentage',
        'tariff_ec_ht',
        'new_tariff_ec_lt',
    )
}} as amount_glb
from {{ ref("my_table") }}
```

Always got the error:

```
  'given_price' is undefined
```

Or if I call the function with quotes on the column names I got :

```
 '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

I printed the output there it shows that the arguments are empty values:

```
the data is :  , , ,
```